# Connection disappears when I spin down airflow docker and then spin it up

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am new to airflow and docker, however, I've been able to get my first DAG to work, using a connection I created using the airflow web servers UI. The connection is simply a username and password using basic authentication to be able to call an API endpoint using requests.get.

I then set the variables like so.

USERNAME = BaseHook.get_connection('my_conn_id').login 
 PASSWORD = BaseHook.get_connection('my_conn_id').password

[image]

When I spin down/up airflow/docker my connection I created disappears and my DAG breaks.

Again, I am very new to all of this and read a ton of documentation but can't seem to figure out how to overcome this.

My end goal is to permanently store these new connection so that I do not need to recreate them everytime.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are -probably- not mapping the postgres volumes. Meaning, you need to persist the data on the host machine, to do that you map a folder of your host machine to your docker container.

As I see you are using docker compose, you can take inspiration from this one:

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml

You need to uncomment some lines (environvent variable settings and volume mapping) as specified:

```
    # Uncomment these lines to persist data on the local filesystem.
    #     - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    # volumes:
    #     - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Hope this was helpful

Comment: is there a nice tutorial you followed setting up airflow w/ docker? Thank you for this advice, I am going to give it a shot.